# C# Application Icon Not Fitting Entire Area

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm facing an issue with my C# application where the icon doesn't seem to fit the entire area. I've set the application icon using the standard method, but it appears to be scaled incorrectly or not filling the designated space.

I've tried adjusting the icon size and resolution, but the problem persists. Has anyone encountered a similar issue, and what could be causing this behavior? Are there specific considerations or settings I should be aware of when setting the application icon in a C# project?

Any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you better describe what you mean by _"where the icon doesn't seem to fit the entire area"_? When you create an icon, you can create it with several different sizes (and but depths). Depending on how it is used, the OS may pick one size or another and do some scaling. It's very hard to get this "right"; depending on user preferences, each use by a different user may result in a different image size being chosen and scaled (and scaling low resolution pixel-based images can mess things up). What is your use case? What image sizes are you using? Why are you dissatisfied?

Comment: @Flydog57 I am on windows and my icon is 256x256. The problem is the icon showing in taskbar is not big as other applications taskbar icon.

Comment: My suggestion: add some other icon sizes to your icon. Just draw it as a rectangle, with some indication of the size (e.g. create a 64x64 icon with a blue rectangle and a 32x32 icon in red). See what happens. Getting icons and icon sizes right enough to make you happy can be tricky and often requires trial and error.

Comment: I just looked at some recent (over the last several years) WinForms apps I've done. The application icon has renderings at 16x16, 32x32 and some at 48x48

Comment: Most web sites that offer icon creation services, allow to convert a PNG image to a composite icon of different sizes, from 16x16 to 256x256 (Jumbo size). Create an icon that contains all of them

Comment: [Here's a page about icon designs from MS that talks about various size uses.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-icons#level-of-detail). Concerning the appearance, they even say, _Simply scaling down from the 256x256 size does not work._